# add custom module position inside HEAD on joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I'm using a script module plugin that allow you to add scripts to a module in joomla, however I need this module to be inside the HEAD tag so I can place the scripts on the correct place.

Is there a way to create a custom module position inside of the head of the index page? so every time i create a module and assign that specific position something like "scriptTop" the script on that module will be placed inside the HEAD tag...

Does that makes sense?

cheers,dan

Answer (score 1):

As nibra said you can add a module name with in your index.php template and you are almost there

```
<head>
...
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="scriptTop" />
...
</head>
```

but if you use an customHTML to add your metatags or code you will have the customHTML module default template with an unwanted div output.

To clean it out you can do a module template override in your own template coping the

modules/mod_custom/tmpl/default.php

into

yourttemplatename/html/mod_custom/newtemplatename.php

and just delete the unwanted divs:

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>

<?php echo $module->content;?>
```

then just select your new template from the modules option when you create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is straight forward. Edit the file `index.php` of your template, and change it this way:

```
<head>
    ...
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="scriptTop" />
    ...
</head>
```

Then any module published in the `scriptTop` position will be rendered in the head section. You must ensure that the code produced by the module is valid to be incorporated into the head section.